# Inconsistent accessibility: TBGE_FilePaths is less accessible than field FilePaths

Tags: c#, io

So while developing my software in C#, I stumpled over this error that just happened. Can't figure out what's wrong, since all of it is public and that shouldn't be the problem?

The full error is:

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: field type
>   'TextbasedGameEngine.DataStorage.TBGE_FilePaths' is less accessible
>   than field
>   'TextbasedGameEngine.GameDesignerForm.FilePaths'  C:\Users\Kevin\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2013\Projects\TextbasedGameEngine\TextbasedGameEngine\Form1.cs    24  31  TextbasedGameEngine

I have the main class "**GameDesignerForm**" as following:

```
...
using TextbasedGameEngine.DataStorage;
using TextbasedGameEngine.Handlers;

namespace TextbasedGameEngine {
    public partial class GameDesignerForm : Form {

        private TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs CurrentSelectedSequence;
        private TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs CurrentSelectedChoice;

        public static GameDesignerForm instance;
        public TBGE_FilePaths FilePaths;

        public GameDesignerForm() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GameDesignerForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            FilePaths = new TBGE_FilePaths(Application.StartupPath);
            instance = this;
            ReloadSave();
        }
    }
}
```

And the class i'm trying to access/use is **TBGE_FilePaths** that's in another folder:

```
...
using TextbasedGameEngine.Handlers;

namespace TextbasedGameEngine.DataStorage {
    class TBGE_FilePaths {
        public string STARTUP_PATH;
        public string LOCATION_PATH;
        public string PROJECT_NAME;

        public string CURRENT_SAVE_FILE = "/TBGE_Data/current_save.txt";
        public string SEQUENCE_SAVE_FILE;
        public string CHOICE_SAVE_FILE;

        public TBGE_FilePaths(string startupPath) {
            //Constructor
            STARTUP_PATH = startupPath;
            PROJECT_NAME = TBGE_FileHandler.GetCurrentSaveFile(STARTUP_PATH + CURRENT_SAVE_FILE);
            LOCATION_PATH = STARTUP_PATH + "/TBGE_Data/SaveFiles/" + PROJECT_NAME + "/";
            SEQUENCE_SAVE_FILE = LOCATION_PATH + "Sequences.xml";
            CHOICE_SAVE_FILE = LOCATION_PATH + "Choices.xml";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `TBGE_FilePaths` class **public**, classes are `internal` by default.

```
public class TBGE_FilePaths
```

Comment: Wow.. Am I really that blind that I could oversee that option? Ofcourse.. that makes so much sense now.. Thank you I guess for the help mate.. I better get on with my debugging skills :D